# How to debug a release build in .NET Core

Tags: debugging, .net-core, release-builds

Normally we cannot debug a **release build** in **Visual Studio** as the code has been optimised. But for **.NET Framework** applications, we can follow the way described in [Debugging Optimized Code in .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miguelnunez/2014/10/06/debugging-optimized-code-in-net/), so ***JIT*** will not optimize the code and we can debug the release build hence.

This approach works perfectly for .NET Framework applications. But I've tried the same way to debug a release build of an Azure Function V2 application in **.NET Core** project (netcoreapp2.1) and it did not work.

So is there a way to debug a release build in .NET Core?

Comment: Where is your .NET Core application deployed?   Is it local?  What operating system?  On the cloud or in a container?  Where?  Where it is deployed affects what methods are available.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft The application is going to deployed on Azure as serverless service, no container used. But when I tried to debug the release build, I had it locally on Windows 10 and used Visual Studio 2017.